# Program skips lines of code

Tags: c#

I have a small program that changes values of char arrays. But first you need to tell the program in **which array** you want to change a value; and write a **new value** and its **position** into that same array position.

But when I enter the array number, the program skips the code lines allowing the entry of the new value and its position. Then the program throws a **FormatException** at the end.

Here's the code:

```
    static void addLetters(char[] messageOne, char[] messageTwo)
    {
        char Mnumber;
        char letter;
        string pos;
        int position;

        Console.Write("- Message #: ");
        Mnumber = (char)Console.Read();

        if (Mnumber == '1')
        {
            Console.Write("Letter: ");
            letter = (char)Console.Read();

            Console.Write("\nPosition: ");
            pos = Console.ReadLine();
            position = Int32.Parse(pos);

            messageOne[position - 1] = letter;
        }

        if (Mnumber == '2')
        {
            Console.Write("Letter: ");
            letter = (char)Console.Read();

            Console.Write("\nPosition: ");
            pos = Console.ReadLine();
            position = Int32.Parse(pos);

            messageTwo[position - 1] = letter;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] array1 = new char[50];
        char[] array2 = new char[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = '*';
            array2[i] = '*';
        }

        addLetters(array1, array2);
    }
}
```

P.S. Could you please tell me how I can make this code more 'elegant'?

Comment: Tell us which lines are giving an error.

Comment: `position = Int32.Parse(pos);` line gives an error

Comment: You might want to use `TryParse` rather than `Parse`.

Comment: If it's in that line, we need to know what you enter.

Comment: I don't enter anything, because the program skips the lines after I enter the message number. I mean it prints **Letter:** and **Position:** but doesn't allow me to enter anything and just goes to the end of function

Comment: Hint: Don't copy and paste the same lines of codes over and over again. Make a function with parameters of things that might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a single character it's reccommended to use Console.ReadKey().KeyChar. I've modified your code to handle exceptions as well:

```
    static void addLetters(char[] messageOne, char[] messageTwo)
    {
        char Mnumber;
        char letter;
        string pos;
        int position;

        try
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("- Message #: ");
                Mnumber = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            while (Mnumber != '1' && Mnumber != '2');

            Console.Write("\nLetter: ");
            letter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            Console.Write("\nPosition: ");
            pos = Console.ReadLine();
            position = Int32.Parse(pos);

            if (Mnumber == '1')
                messageOne[position - 1] = letter;
            else
                messageTwo[position - 1] = letter;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input format, position must be an integer");
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Position out of array bounds");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a single function for both messages, and `TryParse()` your string to integer conversions

```
    static char ReadChar(string prompt)
    {
        // Screen Prompt
        Console.Write(prompt);
        // Read a Character
        return Console.ReadKey(false).KeyChar;
    }
    static int ReadNumber(string prompt)
    {
        // Screen Prompt
        Console.Write(prompt);
        int result=-1;
        // Reads a number and onverts it into an integer
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
        return result;
    }

    // Caution, this modifies the contents of `messages`
    static void addLetters(params char[][] messages)
    {
        // Read message index (first=1, second=2, etc)
        int Mnumber=ReadNumber("- Message #: ");
        // Read letter
        char letter=ReadChar("Letter: ");
        // Read placement position
        int position=ReadNumber("\nPosition: ");
        // Get the right message
        char[] current_message=messages[Mnumber-1];
        // Assigns a letter to the message
        current_message[position]=letter;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n=50; //Store the size instead of hard coding it all over your code
        char[] array1=new char[n];
        char[] array2=new char[n];

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            array1[i]='*';
            array2[i]='*';
        }

        addLetters(array1, array2);
    }
```